# What does the "s!" operator in Perl do?

Tags: python, regex, perl

I have this Perl snippet from a script that I am translating into Python. I have no idea what the "s!" operator is doing; some sort of regex substitution. Unfortunately searching Google or Stackoverflow for operators like that doesn't yield many helpful results.

```
 $var =~ s!<foo>.+?</foo>!!;
 $var =~ s!;!/!g;
```

What is each line doing? I'd like to know in case I run into this operator again.

And, what would equivalent statements in Python be?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`s!foo!bar!` is the same as the more common `s/foo/bar/`, except that foo and bar can contain unescaped slashes without causing problems. What it does is, it replaces the first occurence of the regex foo with bar. The version with g replaces all occurences.

Comment: Perl borrows from a lot of languages. It borrowed this from sed.

Answer (score 13):

It's doing exactly the same as `$var =~ s///`. i.e. performing a search and replace within the `$var` variable.

In Perl you can define the delimiting character following the `s`. Why ? So, for example, if you're matching '/', you can specify another delimiting character ('!' in this case) and not have to escape or backtick the character you're matching. Otherwise you'd end up with (say)

```
s/;/\//g;
```

which is a little more confusing.

[Perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) has more info on this.

Answer (score 10):

Perl lets you choose the delimiter for many of its constructs.  This makes it easier to see what is going on in expressions like

```
$str =~ s{/foo/bar/baz/}{/quux/};
```

As you can see though, not all delimiters have the same effects.  Bracketing characters (`<>`, `[]`, `{}`, and `()`) use different characters for the beginning and ending.  And `?`, when used as a delimiter to a regex, causes the regexes to match only once between calls to the `reset()` operator.

You may find it helpful to read [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) (in particular the sections on [`m/PATTERN/msixpogc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#m/PATTERN/msixpogc), [`?PATTERN?`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#?PATTERN?), and [s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpogce](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpogce)).

Answer (score 3):

`s` is the substitution operator. Normally this uses '/' for the delimiter:

```
s/foo/bar/
```

, but this is not required: a number of other characters can be used as delimiters instead. In this case, '!' has been used as the delimiter, presumably to avoid the need to escape the '/' characters in the actual text to be substituted.

In your specific case, the first line removes text matching '.+?'; i.e. it removes 'foo' tags with or without content.

The second line replaces all ';' characters with '/' characters, globally (all occurences).

The python equivalent code uses the `re` module:

```
f=re.sub(searchregx,replacement_str,line)
```

Comment: "...it removes 'foo' tags with or without content."  Not quite -- it removes 'foo' tags enclosing *at least one* character.  +1, however, for actually showing some pythonic code.

Comment: @pilcrow: Hmm, thanks for the clarification. The '?' here seems superfluous then. I'd assumed '.+?' would work like '(.+)?'. But it doesn't.

Comment: '.+?' means "one or more, but as few as possible while still getting a match". As opposed to '.+' which will match as much as possible.

Answer (score 3):

s is the substitution operator. Usually it is in the form of `s/foo/bar/`, but you can replace // separator characters some other characters like *!*. Using other separator charaters may make working with things like paths a lot easier since you don't need to escape path separators.

See [manual page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) for further info.

You can find similar functionality for python in [re-module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

Answer (score 3):

`s!` is syntactic sugar for the 'proper' `s///` operator. Basically, you can substitute whatever delimiter you want instead of the '/'s.

As to what each line is doing, the first line is matching occurances of the regex `<foo>.+?</foo>` and replacing the whole lot with nothing. The second is matching the regex `;` and replacing it with `/`.

`s///` is the substitute operator. It takes a regular expression and a substitution string.

```
s/regex/replace string/;
```

It supports most (all?) of the normal regular expression switches, which are used in the normal way (by appending them to the end of the operator).

Answer (score 0):

And the python equivalent is to use the `re` module.